# Why does the scanner give java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = 1;
        b = sc.nextInt();
        if (b == 1) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
        int a = 2;
        a = sc.nextInt();
        if (a == 2) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter an integer a second time, I get an error.
On the other hand, the **Online JAVA compiler** does not generate errors, maybe this is a technical error?
If so, how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: `int b = 1; b = sc.nextInt();` is effectively `int b = sc.nextInt();`. Anyway I can't reproduce your problem if I provide two integers. What is the input you are providing to application?

Comment: @PM77-1 Are you sure about that duplicate target? OP example doesn't seem to be using `nextLine()`.

Comment: @Pshemo - OP has two `nextInt()` in a row. Second will consume end-of-line left in the buffer from the first and it will not be `int`..

Comment: But that shouldn't throw `java.util.InputMismatchException` as by default Scanner is using whitespaces as delimiters (and line-separators are also considered as whitespaces).

Comment: I do not believe (could be wrong) that white space is interpreted as zero.

Comment: "*I do not believe (could be wrong) that white space is interpreted as zero.*" true but I am not sure how is that related to anything here (especially where did you get zero from). I am not saying you are wrong, I just can't grasp reasoning behind that comment).

Comment: @Pshemo So this is a technical problem?

Comment: your code works on my computer without any errors - Netbeans12, Java 12 windows

Comment: @JisusSestive Hard to say since I can't reproduce it with your example... Is this the entire code you are executing (at least related to `System.in`)?

Comment: @Pshemo - instead of guessing just ran the code and found out that I was wrong.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, it works in the online compiler, but doesn't want in Eclipse

Comment: I also run it on Eclipse. Worked fine for me...

Comment: `1
yes
2 //input
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Start.main(Start.java:19)`

Comment: Is `1 yes 2` input you used while running? Then `yes` is second *token* Scanner will see. But your code is trying to read second token via `nextInt()` and since `yes` is not int you are getting exception. BUT if that is the case then in online compiler you probably provided different input.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry `yes` is output, input is 1 and 2

Comment: Then still can't reproduce it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZSj9.png

Comment: "I also run it on Eclipse. Worked fine for me...". I will try reinstalling jdk and eclipse

Comment: This works fine for me. I only get an InputMismatchException if I type in something other than an integer for either of the two inputs. BlueJ, Java 11.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I updated the jdk and it worked. In the project settings, JavaSE-15 was specified, I updated the jdk from 15 to 16 and specified jdk 16.0.1 in the project.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your answer to provide a little more detail, specifically the jdk version in which the issue is resolved?  Thanks!